# While Converting Tiff to pdf in python the pdf gets blacked

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tiff, img2pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jH9X.png)Thats the code, the problem is after saving the pdf it appears black. But some tiffs while conversion are saved and converted properly, But some go black.

```
 import json
 import urllib.parse
import boto3
 import os
 import img2pdf
from PIL import Image 

path = r"SI-1.tif"

im = Image.open(path)

(file1, ext) = os.path.splitext(path)
print(file1)
print(ext)
pdf_Path = "static\A.pdf"
if ext.lower() == '.tif' or ext.lower() == '.jpg':

    pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(im.filename)

    # opening or creating pdf file 
    file = open(pdf_Path, "wb") 
        
    # writing pdf files with chunks 
    file.write(pdf_bytes)
```

Comment: This is invalid lambda code. Why it is tagged as `aws-lambda`? Is it supposed to work on lambda?

Comment: Yes I am building it for lambda, but first I am trying to convert it locally. But I am getting this issue.

Comment: You would have to provide an example of the actual files to use.